# How can I change regdomain of a WIFI board in Ubuntu 20.04 - Intel AX200 AP 5G?

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, ap-hotspot

My board is a TP-Link Archer Tx50e which comes with Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200.

**iw list** gives me all frequencies with No IR on 5Ghz band:

```
Frequencies:
                        * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5340 MHz [68] (disabled)
                        * 5360 MHz [72] (disabled)
                        * 5380 MHz [76] (disabled)
                        * 5400 MHz [80] (disabled)
                        * 5420 MHz [84] (disabled)
                        * 5440 MHz [88] (disabled)
                        * 5460 MHz [92] (disabled)
                        * 5480 MHz [96] (disabled)
                        * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
                        * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
                        * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
                        * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
                        * 5885 MHz [177] (disabled)
                        * 5905 MHz [181] (disabled)
```

Also, iw reg get:

```
phy#0 (self-managed)
country 00: DFS-UNSET
...
```

I've tried to change the regdomain to CA, so I did it in /etc/default/crda. Uploaded the driver and loaded again, and with **iw list** I got:

```
Frequencies:
                        * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5340 MHz [68] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5360 MHz [72] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5380 MHz [76] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5400 MHz [80] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5420 MHz [84] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5440 MHz [88] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5460 MHz [92] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5480 MHz [96] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5845 MHz [169] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5865 MHz [173] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5885 MHz [177] (22.0 dBm)
                        * 5905 MHz [181] (22.0 dBm)
```

Cool right? But no... Once I start hostapd all 5G frequencies back to no IR and hostapd says, of course:

> Channel 149 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x20053 NO-IR

So, seems there is no way to make 5G available for AP mode?

In this post seems someone managed to do so, but not in my case (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/636667/why-cant-hostapd-service-start-ap-configured-in-5-ghz-band-using-intel-ax200-ba/637706).

So, I ask: regdomain is being setup in the hardware as well? Why I can't change it?

Currencly my nework is being managed by systemd-network (I use this by choice, even this version is desktop version with KDE Neon).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to know more about this, I've posted in Intel Community as well: https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Intel-AX200-as-AP-in-Ubuntu-20-04-hostapd/m-p/1309476 Basically, is impossible, due automatic DRS/LAR (like @Zaak mentioned it). What a waste of money... Intel should give the option to disable this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue but I don't think there is a solution (I even had a long and "friendly" discussion with Intel Premium Support).

So, I don't know if it's public knowledge but Intel introduced a feature called DRS (Dynamic Regulatory Solution) :
https://blogs.intel.com/technology/2015/01/intel-drs-wi-fi-trouble-international-travelers/

Basically, it means that they do not allow you to control regulatory like before. The card scan your environment by itself at startup and determine where it is (I think it is based on country code from beacon frames). If nothing can be determined then the card will be set into GLOBAL.

Oh ! And this feature cannot be disabled, it's built-in the precompiled proprietary iwlwifi firmware. So, there is nothing we can do.
FYI, all Intel WiFi 6 cards have this feature embedded.

Comment: Yeah, that has to be. Is impossible. But is quiet annoying that those "technicians" from the Intel Community Forum they don't even know that there is a driver for Linux... is a waste of time trying to deal with them.
So, for my home project (Router/Gateway/WIFI AP), now I use 2 USB 3.0 TP-Link T9UH (one for 2.4Ghz and another for 5Ghz), using the driver from https://github.com/morrownr/8814au, and works very good so far.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=CA" > /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

I believe this will properly set the regulatory domain to CA; however, I am not at all confident that it will expose non-IR channels. It does not in the USA. Check:

```
iw list
```

From my US machine, as an example:

```
Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm) (no IR)
```

Comment: Hi, Already tried this and there is no Luck (also there is no need to reboot, you can unload and load the driver again by using modprobe command).

Comment: "there is no Luck" means what exactly? The regulatory domain doesn't persist as CA? Or it doesn't expose non-IR channels? Or what else?

Comment: The regulatory domain does not persist with any country. Once I start hostapd it backs to the same (no-IR and no country regdomain), like I explained in my example in the first post.

Also, is not only that I need to change the regulatory domain, I need to disable "no IR", otherwise 5Gghz can never be used as AP.